# Is it possible to make intranet phone calls, without using the computer?

Tags: networking, home-networking, intranet

I have an intranet network in my building, and i was thinking to use this network to call each other, instead of calling using the normal phone line and pay a lot of money.

Is it possible to put a phone directly on a internet cable and call each other through? or there a better solution?

please advice, because i just have the idea and i know nothing about how to do it.

Comment: without using the computer?!

Comment: yes, just the phone, because if we will use computers, so no need to phones we can use skype or any voice chat application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easily possible...

You just need VOIP based phones that can either use your router and directly link to a third party sip provider, or roll out your own PBX (such as [Trixbox](http://www.trixbox.org)) however, that would require a computer to be on 24x7